# Need Advice for Basic C# Grid Game with User Input

Tags: c#, arrays, int

I'm looking for some guidance towards creating a slider grid for a project of mine.

It will contain a 4x4 grid containing 16 numbers but one space which will be 0 will be classed as the empty space.

The general design of the game is that only the numbers directly around the empty "0" space can be moved.

The user also has to be able to select the number in the grid they wish to try to move.

If someone can just help me format the layout/general basic code involved in making the grid take user input and move them up or down or left or right that would be a great help to me! :)

I have created an array for the grid but that's all I have at the moment code wise due to the fact I'm still trying to solve the problem of making the grid function.

Comment: Sounds like an attempt to implement ["15 puzzle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle).

Comment: Good luck.. This question is too broad for StackOverflow, you might be more welcome over at [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yeah it is 15 puzzle. Cant understand how to format the grid to take user input to move the individual elements and the ones around one specific element being "0"